# Is it possible to get if a stored procedure is called within another stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have 2 stored procedures where the first one calls the second one within a transaction. The second procedure should never be called directly, but only from within its parent.

Currently, to check if this is the case I'm doing the following in the second procedure:

```
DECLARE @inTran bit;
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    SET @inTran= 0
ELSE
    SET @inTran= 1
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I dont know how to do it correct, but this wont work because anyone can start as many transaction as he wants, and thus get `@@TRANCOUNT` up

Comment: If the inner procedure should only ever be called from one outer procedure, why have a separate stored procedure? Why not just embed the logic from the inner procedure directly into the parent?

Comment: @GarethD Because it would make it too complex

Comment: `@@TRANCOUNT` need not have any relation to the number of procedures called, and a procedure call does not in itself begin a new transaction. Getting a "call stack" from within T-SQL is definitely not possible -- at least not since the last time I checked, and I checked pretty hard. You should first try to answer the question of *why* this procedure should not be called except from its parent -- is it just aesthetics, or does it do something dangerous? Can you simply not grant permissions to execute it, or put it in a separate schema (that users have no access to, if necessary)?

Comment: So, you want to check to ensure the stored proc is in a transaction to ensure the sproc was called from another sproc? Even if you can determine there is an active transaction, it doesn't mean that it was called from a sproc. Use proper security in granting permissions only allow that to be executed by other sprocs.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - It is possible to get the call stack from extended events. So in theory it 's not entirely impossible - example. Set up an extended events session capturing `sp_statement_completed` filtered with object id of the child proc. Then have the child proc query that event session to get the latest result for its own session id. But would need to take account latency in extended events so may need a delay added and would need sufficient permissions to query the extended events session and various system DMVs. (And I don't recommend doing this!)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I tried something along those lines once (where the perf impact was no issue), and I didn't succeed in capturing the parameter values of the calls, which made it more or less useless for my purposes at the time. (I have not checked to see if this could somehow be remedied by pulling in even more events.) You're right that for a simple "A called B" stack it would probably be good enough (if wildly impractical for most production scenarios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a casual way to prevent inadvertent execution of the proc on its own. You could also check `@@NESTLEVEL` - this will be at least `2` if called from another proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Child
AS
    IF @@NESTLEVEL < 2 OR @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    THROW 50000, 'Child proc should be called from Parent', 1;
```

Or you could have the parent proc set a value read by `SESSION_CONTEXT()` in the child proc.

None of these will prevent the proc not being run as intended by someone determined to circumvent the restrictions though. They will just guard against accidental misuse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way of doing this. Checking @@trancount only gives you information if you are in a transaction or not, and someone could do this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
EXECUTE nested_proc_directly
```

In this case, the tran count in the proc would b greater than 0. And as others have said you cannot the call stack. So, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading between the lines here a little bit, and guessing that the actual question is how to prevent `Procedure2` from being run by any process except a call from `Procedure1`.

If this has to be as close to totally locked down as possible, create a dedicated service account to run these procedures, or their associated job(s), and then only grant `EXECUTE` permissions on `Procedure2` to that dedicated account.

If "pretty locked down" is good enough, only grant `EXECUTE` permissions on `Procedure2` to the service account you have running your jobs in production. At least that would keep stray users from firing it off willy-nilly.

Another thought would be to create an SSIS package with two `Execute SQL Tasks` in it, with the first containing all the code in `Procedure1` and the second containing all the code in `Procedure2`, then do away with the procs and run the package instead. I don't care for embedding code in packages, though, because maintenance is irritating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@@PROCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/procid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), for this. The only problem is that you need to pass the parameter by input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test1(@id As int)
AS 
PRINT @id
PRINT OBJECT_NAME(@id)
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test2
AS
EXEC usp_Test1 @@PROCID
GO

EXEC usp_Test2
GO
```

output

```
1054730910
usp_Test2
```